# convert actionlink into a href in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use

```
 @Html.ActionLink("buyer", "buyer", new { Email = Model.Owner.Email })
```

as a link and role of button.

if it does not have 3rd part I could handle it as a

```
 <a class="btn btn-danger" href="buyer" >new buyer</a>
```

but because of

```
 new { Email = Model.Owner.Email }
```

I do not know how can I change `<a ....>` to work correctly.

Comment: What is wrong with using `ActionLink`? You can just add the class name to it (by adding `new { @class = "btn btn-danger" }` as the 4th parameter. but if you want to do it manually, then use `href="@Url.Action("buyer", new { Email = Model.Owner.Email })"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks a lot. you have been so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Action Link like this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Your Link Text", "Your Action", new { Email = Model.Owner.Email }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Put This and you can use it like that.

```
@Html.ActionLink("buyer", "buyer", new { @class="btn btn-danger"}, new{ Email = Model.Owner.Email })
```

Comment: No you cant (its adding a route value, not a html attribute)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: the HtmlAttribute parameter has been misplaced with RouteValues in his code. But he was very close.

Comment: @Transcendent, Look at the edit history :) (it was worse when I made the comment, and the edit is still wrong)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: yeah I just saw that, you are 100% right :)